# finish my search input using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I know i've posted like 30 min ago but i think i am getting close with my search posts input:

i've created a model that looks like this

```
    function matchPosts($keyword)
{
    $this->db->get('posts');
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT title,body FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%$keyword%' or body LIKE '$keyword%' AND status='published'");        
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data = $query->row_array();
    }       
    $query->free_result();
    return  $data;
}
```

i am trying to get a match from my database,

the controller looks like this:

```
public function searchPosts()
{
    $keyword = $this->input->post('search_value', TRUE);

    $matched_field = $this->Model_cats->matchPosts($keyword);

    echo $keyword;

    if( count($matched_field) > 0)
    {
        $this->load->view('posts_list');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('posts_list');
    }
}
```

this is the js file

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#search_posts").keyup(function()
    {        
        var searchValue = $(this).val();

        $(".posted_post").each(function()
        {
               $.ajax({             
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "http://local.blog.com/welcome/searchPosts",
                    data: {
                        search_value: searchValue   
                    },  
                    success: function(data)
                    { 
                        if(data)
                        {
                            $(this).show(); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(this).fadeOut();      
                        }

                    }
                });
        });
    });
});
```

and the view:

```
    <br>    
<form action="" method="post"> 
        <label for="search_posts"><b>Search Posts</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="search_posts" value="" />
</form>
```

posts_list is the view where i loop throught the posts...

Em i getting close? it doesn't work in this state.

Comment: You seem to be vulnerable to SQL injection - eg what if you type `' OR 1=1--` into your search box? (Or worse `' OR 1=1; DROP TABLE posts--`)?

Comment: i've updated my code.. why is it not working now? ...... @Basic i just want it to work.. then i will make this secure

Comment: Paul, can you break down which bit, exactly, isn't working? You can use Firebug/browser dev tools/similar to monitor the requests/responses to the server. Are they being fired? Do they contain the correct information? Are you getting http 200 responses? Do they contain the results you'd expect? etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your script as

```
$("#search_posts").keyup(function()
{        
    var posts = $(this).val();        
    //$(".posted_post").each(function()
    //{
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://local.blog.com/welcome/searchPosts',
            data: {posts},  
            success : function(data)
            {
                 $(this).show();
            }
        });
    //}
});
```

and from

```
$matched_field = $this->Model_cats->matchPosts($keyword);
```

the $matched_field returns number of search results found right..??then you just check like

```
if($matched_field)
{
      //Here you can print result of search
}
else
{
      //You can print No results found
}
```

Comment: well stil doesn't work... i update with your code and made some changes but.. still doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

In your match_posts function you are using num_rows 
() in your search posts function you are gathering result from above function and comparing with boolean true using === . Try var dump to confirm what type of value gets return from num rows function. I think you are comparing numeric with boolean . Instead you can use if count (matched fields) > 0

Comment: ok.. still doesn't work... @ Shridhar .. and i made updates on my code

Comment: Ok , I think you need to debug matchPost function to confirm sql statement is well formatted and is actually returning data as you are expecting.  I did notice that you have only one % on body match . That may be be you are expecting as it is.  In search post function you are only checking count but not actually passing value to view. See if else statement.  You are having view ( post_list ) . What that do. Do you need to assign matchPost return data to view

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
class SomeModel extends CI_Model{

    /**
     * Get Posts
     * 
     * @param string LIKE param
     * @return mixed Object/Array or Boolean
     **/
    public function get_posts( $like ){

        $query = 
        $this->db
             ->select('id, title, body')
             ->like('title'   => $like)
             ->or_like('body' => $like) //not sure if your looking for FULLTEXTSEARCH on this body
             ->get_where('posts', array('status' => 'published'));


        return ( $query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : FALSE;
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
//edit to match your class/method
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'welcome/search_posts/$1';
```

**Controller**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller{

    public function search_posts( $like ){

        if( !$posts = $this->SomeModel->get_posts( $like ))
        {
            return show_404();
        }

        //return partial view without template
        return $this->load->view('public_home', array(
            'posts' =>  $posts
        ), TRUE);
    }
}
```

**Partial View(for ajax)**

```
/**
<ul>
    //<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <li>
        <a href=#>
            <h4><?php echo html_escape($post->title) ?></h4>
            <p>
                <?php echo html_escape($post->body) ?>
            </p>
        </a>
    </li>
    //<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
**/
```

**JQuery**

```
var SITEURL = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";

;(function($){

    var search = {
        init: function(){

            if($('#search_posts'))
            {
                this.searchPosts();
            }

        },
        searchPosts : function(){

            var searchInput = $("#search_posts")
                result      = $("#result"),
                timeout     = '';

            //ajax request
            var doAjax = function( context, data ){
                $.ajax({
                    cache    : false,
                    url      : SITEURL + 'search/' + data.keyword,
                    dataType : 'html',
                    type     : 'POST',
                    data     : data,
                    context  : context,
                    success  : function( callback ){
                        $(this).html( callback ); //$(this) = context => $("#result")
                    }
                });
            };

            //delayed keyup event
            searchInput.on('keyup', function( event ){

                if(timeout) {
                    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = null;
                }

                //listen for keyup after delayed(1000)
                timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
                    var inputVal = $(this).val();
                    var data     = {
                        'keyword'   : inputVal
                    }
                    return doAjax( result, data );//execute ajax function
                }, 1000);

            });




        }
    };

    $(function(){
        search.init();
    });

})(jQuery);
```